# Dictionaries inside a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an array that is filled with dictionaries, one for each day. Inside each dictionary I have a list of exercises and inside each exercise is an array with two values. The program I am writing has a picker for several workout programs which is saved as an integer called programInt. I also have a method which converts this Int to a string called programPickerText. Here is the code I have so far:

```
    // create array
    self.liftData = [NSMutableArray array];

    // fill array with dictionaries, one for each day
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        [self.liftData setObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] atIndexedSubscript:i];

        // create an array for exercises
        self.liftData[i][@"Exercise1"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
        self.liftData[i][@"Exercise2"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
        self.liftData[i][@"Exercise3"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
        self.liftData[i][@"Exercise4"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
        self.liftData[i][@"Exercise5"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
        self.liftData[i][@"Exercise6"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];

        NSLog(@"array is %@", self.liftData);
      }
```

I basically need my mutable array (self.liftData) to be able to save information in the following format:

```
self.liftData[program][day][@"Exercise1"][0]
```

Currently it saves data like:

```
self.liftData[Day][@"Exercise1"][0]
```

Comment: So, add the array/dictionary you need for the added level of indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it's very useful to actually make use of named variables

```
// Create an array of programs
NSMutableArray* programArray = [NSMutableArray array];
self.liftData = programArray;

for (int programIndex = 0; programIndex < ....???...) {

    // Add an array of days to the program
    NSMutableArray* dayArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [programArray addObject:dayArray];

    // fill dayArray with dictionaries, one for each day
    for (int dayIndex = 0; dayIndex < 5; dayIndex++){

        // Add a dictionary of exercises to the day
        NSMutableDictionary* exerciseDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dayArray addObject:exerciseDict];

        // Fill exerciseDict with exercises
        exerciseDict[@"Exercise1"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
        exerciseDict[@"Exercise2"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
        exerciseDict[@"Exercise3"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
        exerciseDict[@"Exercise4"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
        exerciseDict[@"Exercise5"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
        exerciseDict[@"Exercise6"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
    }
}
NSLog(@"The program array is %@", self.liftData);
```

Comment: Just plugged this in and it works great!!!! Thank you so much! I am fairly new to programming and I have been having some difficulty understanding and dealing with nested arrays.

Comment: @user3334789 -- Always go a step at a time, being careful to maintain good variable naming and good indentation of your loops, etc.  Reuse the same pattern at each level (to the extent that it makes sense) so that something out of place will be more apparent.  This makes the code much less intimidating.

Comment: @user3334789 - And don't forget the comments.  I've been in code reviews where the programmer (justifiably) got more criticism for poor comments than for buggy code.  Very often you find that in writing a comment you realize you're coding something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just add one more NSMutableArray?

```
// create array
self.liftData = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *programmArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[self.liftData addObject:programmArray];

// fill array with dictionaries, one for each day
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

    [programmArray setObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] atIndexedSubscript:i];

    // create an array for exercises
    programmArray[i][@"Exercise1"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
    programmArray[i][@"Exercise2"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
    programmArray[i][@"Exercise3"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
    programmArray[i][@"Exercise4"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
    programmArray[i][@"Exercise5"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
    programmArray[i][@"Exercise6"] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];

    NSLog(@"array is %@", self.liftData);
  }
```

Comment: you can even make it a mutable dictionary if the exercises have meanings to you (instead of just 0-n).

Answer (score 1):

I think Avt's answer missed one layer. Before an answer, let me say this: sometimes when your data representation gets complicated and deep enough, it makes sense to create some classes and abstract away the internal representation so you can use readable method names. For example, `[myProgram getExerciseArrayForDay:CONST_WEEKDAY_TUESDAY];` Not only does this make code more readable and easier to get right, but if you change the underlying data representation the code changes are very localized. That said, here's a way of using lots of methods to avoid getting myself confused.

```
self liftData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[self.liftData addObject:[self newProgram] forKey:@"firstProgram"];


-(NSMutableArray *) newProgram(){
    NSMutableArray *program = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        [program addObject:[self newDayExercises]];
    }
    return program;
}

-(NSMutableDictionary *) newDayExercises {
    static NSArray *keyNames = @[@"Exercise1", @"Exercise2", @"Exercise3", @"Exercise4", @"Exercise5", @"Exercise6"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dayExercises = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for(NSString *keyName in keyNames) {
        [dayExercises addObject:@{@"", @""} forKey:keyName]; // note handy NSDictionary initializer
    }
    return dayExercises;
}
```

Comment: Actually, what makes more sense is to simply give each level a name (pointer), vs chaining the multiple indexing operations together.

Comment: Yup, `program1.tuesday.exercise1` is pretty damn readable, or `liftdata.program1.days[2].exercises[1]`